# failed to create a new maven project

Tags: maven

while creating new maven project i am getting an error like this.

```
Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7, 
org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, 
commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0, 
org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, 
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, 
classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, 
org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6,
org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, 
org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6,
```

Comment: pls help me i am using eclips juno Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800 version.pls help me i am behind this since from last 3 days...help me

Comment: Create your project on command line and test it there and not inside Eclipse. It looks like you can't download dependencies (Firewall/Proxy issues?) ...

Comment: yea ,i dont know what is the pblm actlly?,i have installed maven integration  for the eclipse from eclipse market place.After that i was trying to create 1 maven pjct,but it is showing two dialogue box with above errors,,,,i dnt knw how to create a pjct through cmmnd prmpt

Comment: plks help me,,,,,, but rest of the guys are able to install this one in their sm

Comment: are you behind a proxy? these artifacts are all available in the maven central repository. If so you need to configure it in settings.xml: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html